# Xcode 4 fails to load plug-in

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins

With XCode 4.0.2, i have build a plug-in, that was previously working with XCode 3.2, I installed my plug-in in "~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/"

When i open XCode after install my plug-in, i get that crash,

Xcode3UI cannot be loaded, what can be that?

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Couldn't load plug-in 
'com.apple.dt.IDE.Xcode3UI' while firing fault for extension 
'Xcode.Xcode3UI.Initializer'
UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 
UserInfo=0x20029d4e0 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" 
Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3588 
UserInfo=0x2004c7ea0 \"The bundle \U201cXcode3UI\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded.\")";
}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff86093796 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff8412c0f3 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x000000010001c058 -[DVTExtension _fireExtensionFault] (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000100005fdc __38-[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:]
_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff81b454db dispatch_barrier_sync_f (in libSystem.B.dylib)
  5  0x0000000100005f83 -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  6  0x000000010001bde5 -[DVTExtension _valueForKey:inParameterData:usingSchema:] (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010001bd44 -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x000000010050e9dc _IDEInitializeOnePlugInAndPrerequisites (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x000000010050e260 IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
 10  0x000000010084d69c -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] (in IDEKit)
 11  0x00007fff8361b8ea _nsnote_callback (in Foundation)
 12  0x00007fff8603b000 __CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 13  0x00007fff86027578 _CFXNotificationPostNotification (in CoreFoundation)
 14  0x00007fff8361284e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 15  0x00007fff8443e6fd -[NSApplication finishLaunching] (in AppKit)
 16  0x00007fff8443e350 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 17  0x00007fff844371a8 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 18  0x0000000100000eec
 19  0x0000000000000002
```

Here is the linker output

```
/Users/jose/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/slice2objcplugin.pbplugin/Contents/MacOS/slice2objcplugin:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 15.0.0)
    @rpath/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsCore (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2002.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 751.29.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 227.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.29.0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It means; Xcode 4 is not Xcode 3

Comment: @JustSid I have build the plug-in with XCode 4, and have not XCode 3 installed on that machine, how can be that it sill references Xcode 3.

Answer (score 2):

I what *might* be a similar problem to this, and your question came up in my google search, so while it's a slightly different error message - the scenario is similar enough that I thought I'd respond.  This might help you out.

According to this site:  http://johnattebury.com/blog/2011/07/xcode-from-snow-leopard-to-lion/ a re-install of iTunes may fix this.

My error is closer to the one on the above website than it is to yours, but all three relate to plug-in issues between Xcode 3/10.6 and Xcode 4/10.7... perhaps I'm reaching for straws for you, but I thought I'd toss it out there.  It resolved my issue, so perhaps it will take care of yours too?

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i have already solved my problem, in my case i rebuild my plug-in, using a different RPATH, "/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks" by doing that the correct Xcode3UI lib is picked up and the problem goes away. And get my Xcode3 custom plug-in working with Xcode4

Comment: Re-installing iTunes fixed it for me; just done a Snow Leopard to Lion update.